Installing swig on Macos-14-arm64 on github runner
The default MacOS runner on github seems to have changed from MacOS-12 to MacOS-14-arm64.  While the former included "swig, it doesn't seem to be installed in the latter.
What is the correct command for installing "swig" on this github runner?
Any ideas why it isn't included anymore?
